# Not able to Sync my Outlook mail server to my localhost server using imap_open

Tags: email, stream, office365, imap, imap-open

When trying to get all mails from mailbox I got this error:

**Warning**: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/tls}INBOX in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Phpimapdoc\index.php** on line **8**
Cannot connect to Outlook: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

My code is

```
/* connect to outlook */
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/tls}INBOX';
$username = 'mailid@outlook.com';
$password = 'password123';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password, NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI')) or die('Cannot connect to Outlook: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
```

```
/* connect to outlook */
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/tls}INBOX';
$username = 'mailid@outlook.com';
$password = 'password123';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password, NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI')) or die('Cannot connect to Outlook: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
```

The output has to stream all my outlook mails

Comment: O365 does not allow password-based authentication.  However, I am not sure what your alternatives for PHP_IMAP.